# Moving Selected rows Between Gridviews

Tags: asp.net, gridview, move, selected

I currently have Gridview1 which gets it's data from a database and displays a list of people.I also have a Gridview2 which is initially blank. 
I would like to add the functionality of adding/removing rows to gridview2 from gridview1.
I've added a checkbox column to gridview1 to allow users to select the records they'd like to  move. I've also added two buttons >> and <<.
Does anyone have an example of how i can add/remove selected records from Gridview1 to Gridview2?

thanks in advance!

Comment: This can help you, I tried and it works :
http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/10/08/move-multiple-rows-between-gridviews.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
 Gridview2.rows.add(Gridview1.rows[INDEXTOMOVE]);
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to access the Rows.Add Method on a gridview. 
Am i missing something?